# Is there an easy way to print the GTK and QT versions installed on a system?

Tags: scripting, gtk, version, qt

Is there an easy way to print the GTK and QT versions installed on a system? I am wanting to make a script that will print the version numbers of various developer tools and libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask `pkg-config`.

```
$ pkg-config --modversion gtk+-2.0
2.24.18
```

Comment: It would be good that it also handle if libraries aren't installed.

Comment: Using `pkg-config` on a non-existent .pc file results in a non-zero return code.

Comment: I am writing the code like this (pkg-config --modversion gtk+-3.0 2>/dev/null || echo "GTK3 is not installed")

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, thanks. This command is excellent.

Comment: If you're only testing for presence and not the specific version then you don't need to pass `--modversion`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, The way the script works, it is meant to print the version. If the library does not exist, I want the script to print a statement.